# SOQL not returning row (when it should be)

Tags: soql, platform-bug

Running into a very weird issue that is actually causing preventing my IDE from compiling (mavensmate)...

When Mavensmate compiles, it first checks the server version of the file to make sure it can safely be overwritten.

The query it executes looks like this:

```
Select LastModifiedById, LastModifiedDate, LastModifiedBy.Name, Body 
From ApexClass Where Name = :FILENAME
```

I noticed a single file wasn't compiling after some debugging, it turns out that this step wasn't returning any results. 
[image]

However, if I run a more generalized query it shows up.
[image]
***Note: if I change this query to ***`LIKE 'QuoteController2%'` ***it disappears again.***

Any idea what might be going on?  Seems like it could be a platform bug (3rd one this week. I'm on a roll).

Comment: Hello NSjonas, 
I have executed your same query, the one giving the problem, and I get output as expected.

Comment: ya, I mean it gets executed everytime I save a file and 99.99999 % of the time it works.  Not sure what's going on with this file, that's causing it to fail.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: chrome, but the query fails when a raw API request is made so I'm sure it has nothing to do with the browser

Answer (score -1):

try below query its working fine.

```
Select name ,LastModifiedById, LastModifiedDate, LastModifiedBy.name
From ApexClass where name like 'QuoteController2%' order by LastModifiedDate desc
```